# MYSQL get COUNT of highest column value for different phases

Tags: mysql

This is a pretty complicated database. So I have simplified the structure for easy understanding.

I have 2 tables
TABLE A : transactions

```
p_id     rev_count
1        1
2        1
3        1
1        1
1        1
1        2 (Gets incremented as it has reached max entries)
2        1
2        1
2        2 (Gets incremented as it has reached max entries)
1        2
2        2
```

TABLE B : rev_countReference

```
p_id     rev_count
1        2
2        2
3        1
```

So basically Table B stores the rev_count value as reference for TABLE A. Since p_id can accept only 3 transactions, whenever p_id goes exceeds 3 count the rev_count value is incremented and next p_id entry will have an incremented rev_count value.

*QUESTION*
I want to get number of transactions occupied in the maximum rev_count by each p_id.

Desired Output :

```
p_id      used_rev
1         1
2         2
3         1
```

Tried so far :

Unfortunately i'm not able to write a code for the above DB example yet. But what I have tried so far with actual code.

```
public function getfreeslots($user_id) {
        
        $this->db->select('count(t.id), t.reinvest_count, MAX(t.reinvest_count) AS max_reinvest, COUNT(t.id) AS outstandingSlots'); 
        $this->db->from('transactions t'); 
        $this->db->join('reinvestCount rc', "t.receiver_id=rc.user_id AND t.phase_id=rc.phase_id",'LEFT'); 
        $this->db->where('t.receiver_id', $user_id);
        
        $this->db->having('t.reinvest_count >= max_reinvest');
        $this->db->group_by('t.phase_id');
        $this->db->order_by('t.phase_id', 'ASC');
        
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $row = $query->result();
        
        if (empty($row))
            return FALSE;
        return $row;
        
    }
```

I'm using Codeigniter query builder. So answer using query builder will be much appreciated.

Comment: So many 1s and 2s. I can't see how the result set relates to the data set. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `I want to get number of transactions occupied in the maximum rev_count by each p_id.` p_id 1 has 2 transactions at rev_count 2